# Declaring nested arrays in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have the following class that a user will instantiate via a form

```
import { User } from "./User";
import { LearningObjective } from "./LearningObjective";
import { Structure } from "./Structure";

export class Technique {
  id                    : string;
  name                  : string;
  description           : string;
  rules                 : string[];
  delivery_mode         : string[];
  interaction           : string[];
  interrelationship     : string[];
  motivation            : string[];
  participation         : string[];
  performance           : string[];
  resolution_scope      : string[];
  feedback_use          : string[];
  target_audience       : number[];
  learning_objectives   : LearningObjective[];
  affective_objectives  : string[];
  social_objectives     : string[];
  structure             : Structure;
  psychologist          : User;
}
```

My problem lies in the structure field, as a User will define the field as an array of Module, which in turn contain an array of Phase and each phase can have an array of Task

```
export class Task {
  type        : string;
  description : string;
  role        : string;
  resources   : string[];
}

export class Phase {
  name  : string;
  tasks : Task[];
}

export class Module {
  name   : string;
  phases : Phase[];
}

export class Structure {
  modules : Module[];
}
```

I've declared my form as the following

```
  form  : Partial<Technique> = {
    name                  : "",
    description           : "",
    rules                 : [],
    delivery_mode         : [],
    interaction           : [],
    interrelationship     : [],
    motivation            : [],
    participation         : [],
    performance           : [],
    resolution_scope      : [],
    feedback_use          : [],
    target_audience       : [],
    learning_objectives   : [],
    affective_objectives  : [],
    social_objectives     : [],
    structure             : {
      modules: [{
        name: "",
        phases: [{
          name: "",
          tasks: []
        }]
      }]
    }
  };
```

However when I try defining my own structure

```
let Module = {name: "teste", phases: [{name: "phase", tasks: [{type: "tipo", description: "", role: "", resources: []}]}]};
this.form.structure.modules.push(Module);
```

I get the following error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'phases' does not exist on type 'Module[]'.
```

How can I declare my form.structure?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only problem is that you've capitalized the `M` in `Module`, so your variable has exactly the same name as a type. If you follow standard conventions and make the variable all lower case, it works. I can't post a link to the playground because it's too long for a comment and SO has a problem with URL shorteners, but if you copy [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2cHZT5Bs) into [the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), there are no errors.

Comment: Yes you're correct, missed that typo, thanks for pointing it out.
On a related note, if I wanted to access the field name of phases on my html how would I go about doing it?
*ngFor="let mod of form.structure.modules.phases"
and {{mod.name}} doesn't seem to produce any results.

Comment: `form.structure.modules` is an array, it doesn't have a `phases` property; it contains zero or more objects that have `phases` properties. I don't do Angular, but in JavaScript you'd loop over `modules` and then loop over `phases`: `for (const module of form.structure.modules) { for (const phase of module.phases) { /*...*/ } }`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to achieve the results I wanted with a couple of ng-container with ngFor